# How do I return a matrix with joblib Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I have a function that return a list. I am using joblib for parallel processing.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def myFunc(c, K, N):
    # something
    return myList
inputs = range(500)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    val = Parallel(n_jobs=20)(delayed(myFunc)(c, K, N) for c in inputs)
```

I would like to store all the retruned lists `val` in each iteration from 1 through 500 and then use them.

Without the parallel I would do it as:

```
def myFunc(c, K, N):
    # something
    return myList
inputs = range(500)
lists = []
for c in inputs:
    val = myFunc(c, K, N)
    lists.append(val)
# Now I have all the lists
```

Can I do this with parallel?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `joblib.Parallel` do the job for you.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import random


def my_func(c, K, N):
    my_list = [random.randrange(3) for _ in range(K*N)]
    return my_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = range(2)
    K, N = 3, 3
    val = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(my_func)(c, K, N) for c in inputs)
    print(val)
```

This will print

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0]]
```